# resultSet.rowUpdated() throwing a createSQLFeatureNotSupportedException

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to update a row in database. Everything else is working fine, deleting, creating, listing, but editing a row is giving me a createSQLFeatureNotSupportedException

```
@Override
    public Boolean editarUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException {
        try(Connection connection = MySqlConnection.abrirConexao()){
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from usuario where idUsuario = " + usuario.getIdUsuario());

            if (resultSet.first()) {
                resultSet.updateInt("IdUsuario", usuario.getIdUsuario());
                resultSet.updateString("Login", usuario.getLogin());
                resultSet.updateString("Senha", usuario.getSenha());
                resultSet.updateBoolean("Admin",usuario.isAdmin());
                resultSet.updateBoolean("Operador",usuario.isOperador());
                resultSet.updateBoolean("Cliente",usuario.isCliente());
                resultSet.updateRow();
                return resultSet.rowUpdated();
            }

        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This line [`return resultSet.rowUpdated();`] is giving me this exception.
I just want to update a row.

What I doing wrong?

Here is my MySqlConnection

```
public class MySqlConnection {
    public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webticket?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    public static String usuario = "root";
    public static String senha = "123456";

    public static Connection abrirConexao() throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
    }
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
04-Dec-2018 09:00:36.294 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\DevTools\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager]
04-Dec-2018 09:00:36.344 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\DevTools\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager] has finished in [49] ms
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLFeatureNotSupportedException(SQLError.java:236)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.UpdatableResultSet.rowUpdated(UpdatableResultSet.java:1183)
    at br.edu.fapi.webticket.usuario.dao.impl.UsuarioDAOImpl.editarUsuario(UsuarioDAOImpl.java:125)
    at br.edu.fapi.webticket.usuario.dao.impl.OperadorDAOImpl.editarUsuario(OperadorDAOImpl.java:22)
    at br.edu.fapi.webticket.usuario.web.OperadorEditar.doPost(OperadorEditar.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the MySQL Connector/J implementation. The `ResultSet.rowUpdated()` method is only optional for `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` result sets, but apparently MySQL Connector/J has misinterpreted this as 'the method is optional' and have simply implemented it to always throw a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` (see [`UpdatableResultSet.rowUpdated`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/result/UpdatableResultSet.java#L1182) in MySQL Connector/J sources).

I suggest that you file a bug with MySQL.

From the [`ResultSet.rowUpdated()` apidoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#rowUpdated--) (specifically the **Note**):

> Retrieves whether the current row has been updated. The value returned
>   depends on whether or not the result set can detect updates.
>
> **Note**: Support for the `rowUpdated` method is optional with a result set concurrency of `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`
>
> **Returns**:
>       `true` if the current row is detected to have been visibly updated by the owner or another; `false` otherwise
>   **Throws**:
>       `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set
>       `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` - if the JDBC driver does not support this method

As a solution (or workaround), I suggest that you replace `return resultSet.rowUpdated();` with `return true;`. Given the `resultSet.updateRow()` succeeded, you can be sure you updated the row (although possibly you have updated it with the same values it already had).

Especially as `rowUpdated`, given the definition, doesn't necessarily report what you think it does. Its use is primarily to detect concurrent visible updates when scrolling, not to detect your own explicit updates. See also [`DatabaseMetaData.updatesAreDetected`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#updatesAreDetected-int-).

Answer (score 0):

First you can try to change your query in an update query:

```
statement.executeQuery("update usuario set IdUsuario = " 
                      + usuario.getIdUsuario() + ", Login=" + usuario.getLogin()
                      + "where idUsuario = "+ usuario.getIdUsuario());
```

In the code above I showed how to do it for the first two fields but you can add all fields you need.

Explanation: not all JDBC driver supports `updateRow()` method. That's why you get that exception, your current driver does not support that method. It is better to use the `UPDATE` statement. In this way you will see your update work on every JDBC driver you are using.

Also: do not use string concatenation to compose your queries. It is exposed to SQL Injection. Use `PreparedStatement` correctly to avoid this kind of vulnerability in your code. Like the following:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
  "UPDATE usuario SET IdUsuario = ?, Login= ? WHERE idUsuario = ?");
ps.setInt(1,usuario.getIdUsuario());
ps.setString(2, usuario.getLogin());
ps.setInt(3,usuario.getIdUsuario());
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close(); //<- always close PreparedStatement when you are done
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating a table row: this is how it is done using JDBC API. Note usage of `PreparedStatement` and its `executeUpdate` method:

```
String DML = "UPDATE usuario " +
             "SET IdUsuario = ?, " +
                  "Login = ?, " +
                  "Senha = ?, " +
                  "Admin = ?, " +
                  "Operador = ?, " +
                  "Cliente = ? " +
             "WHERE idUsuario = ?";

try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(DML)) {

    pstmt.setInt(1, usuario.getIdUsuario()); 
    pstmt.setString(2, usuario.getLogin()); 
    pstmt.setString(3, usuario.getgetSenha());  
    pstmt.setBoolean(4, usuario.getisAdmin()); 
    pstmt.setBoolean(5, usuario.isOperador());
    pstmt.setBoolean(6, usuario.isCliente());
    pstmt.setBoolean(7, usuario.getIdUsuario());

    int noOfRowsUpdated = pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch(SQLException ex) {
    // handle the exception here...
}
```

NOTE: I am assuming column `IdUsuario` is the primary key for the table - in such case, and you don't need to set its value again during the update.

Comment: Here is the Oracle's Java's JDBC tutorial topic on [Using PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score -1):

try  updating the jdbc driver based on your mysql version

Comment: The drivers are compatible, I read the documentation, and I use the same thing in other project and  just works fine.